# High CPU usage in Eclipse when nothing in progress

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this problem with eclipse Mars.2

Build Automatically is disabled and nothing is in progress.
Each time I start eclipse, there is a high CPU usage. Here is what JProfiler says:
[image]

Eclipse seems to be compiling something, by why?

Another strange thing is that if I try to quit Eclipse, the process does not terminate.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that just Eclipse indexing your projects for faster lookup?
Does the CPU usage go down after a little while?

Comment: I thought it was indexing too, but cpu keep high, and according to the profiler, it does not seem to be indexing files.

Comment: That's literally what the `indexing` part of the package name in one of the stack entries means. You'll find different behavior if you upgrade to **Neon**, as many of the internals of the JavaScript tools have been changed.

Comment: Not really a programming question (more software support), but if you're finding Eclipse slow you'll probably find the situation much better with IntelliJ.

Comment: Then why ecplise.exe does not terminate when I exit?

Comment: It's Eclipse.  I'd suggest finding a better IDE

Comment: I would use IntelliJ if my boss paid for it :)

Comment: Netbeans isn't great but even that's better than Eclipse :)

Comment: @julaudo IntelliJ's community edition is free, even for commercial usage, and it's got all the core features you need for regular Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on Javascript files using Eclipse JavaScript Editor? - Seems to be it's indexing javascript files (JSDT - JavaScript development tools) during the eclipse startup, usually indexing will take some amount of time to parse the files,index the functions and variables for content assist/proposals purpose.